# How to import fontforge to python in windows 7

Tags: python, windows, fontforge

Environment: Win 7, Python 3.4, Sublime Text 2

I am trying to [use fontforge as in following example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124130/import-a-sequence-of-svg-files-into-fontforge-as-glyphs-and-output-a-font-file), by importing fontforge in *.py:

```
import fontforge
font = fontforge.open('blank.sfd')
...
```

However, I haven't found any help for win 7 on where (or which subset) to include fontforge binary in my project to make it work. Any ideas, please? Thanks

Edit:
I was trying to build it with pyextension in win 7 as described here:

http://fontforge.org/source-build.html#MS

via cygwin it fails on executing
    ./configure --enable-pyextension

```
throwing
checking for gcc
result: no    
checking for cc
result: no
checking for cl.exe
result: no
error: in `/cygdrive/c/fontforge':
no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

Edit 2:
By installing C compiler I've managed to ./configure it but my attempts have failed on executing make install command. I got following error, preceding another countless lines:

```
Makefile:91: recipe for target '../libfontforge.la' failed
make[1]: *** [../libfontforge.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/fontforge/fontforge'
Makefile:28: recipe for target 'fontforge' failed
make: *** [fontforge] Error 2
```

Comment: What is the error when you `import fontforge`. Did you build FF with the Python extension enabled?

Comment: @allcaps I was trying to build it with pyextension in win as described here:

http://fontforge.org/source-build.html#MS

via cygwin it fails on 
./configure --enable-pyextension

throwing
checking for gcc
result: no
checking for cc
result: no
checking for cl.exe
result: no
error: in `/cygdrive/c/fontforge':
no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Comment: You need to install a C compiler and try again.

Comment: Thanks, @allcaps, I've installed a C compiler, but I've failed on another command getting an error as described above. Do you have any idea, why it might be so?

Comment: Nope, can't help you. Maybe the Fontforge mailing list?

Comment: Did you manage to do this eventually? And in that case, how? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: HI @akvilas I'm sorry I haven't managed to do it. Any progress at your side?

Comment: @zap I gave up as well. I'm now using FontTools, which had the functionality I needed. But it would be great if there was a way to access FontForge from python in windows... short of doing a windows build of course.

Answer (score 11):

Install [fontforge for windows](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/), then search your install for a `fontforge-console.bat`, and double-click it. From there you have a python environment that includes fontforge via the command:

`ffpython`

e.g.:

`ffpython yourPythonFontForgeScript.py`

You may need to `cd` to whatever directory has your python script before running that command, or otherwise make sure that the script is in your `%PATH%`.

Comment: Thanks, got me where I needed to be. using windows and not cygwin, but meh

Comment: This is probably a helpful answer for most folks just trying to get *some* Python scripting to work with FontForge on Windows (it definitely helped me), but it's worth noting that `ffpython` is FontForge's own copy of Python (not your system's Python), and if you simply downloaded the prebuilt Windows installer (as of this writing, `FontForge-2017-07-31-Windows-r2.exe`), then `ffpython` is Python 2, not Python 3. (Specifically, the 2017-07-31 build contains Python 2.7.13.)

Comment: Running ffpython somescript.py still produces an error if you add `import fontforge` at the top. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fontforge'` (At least for me)

Comment: @Jay you run fontforge-console.bat. When that is done, in the same window, run ffpython, as if it were any other python interpreter.