# How to install FontForge Python plugin for Windows

Tags: python, fontforge

I need some help with installation of FontForge Python on Windows.

I am trying to get ffpython to be usable across the whole system by

1. adding appropriate entried from fontforge-console.bat
2. redirecting the Python Path to FontForge installation path

The console said that Python is missing .dll files and I do not know what happened.

I tried searching for installation that comes with Python installation and came up nothing. THe documentations are too old and didn't give enough information to build my own. Current version is 2019-08-01 on Windows 10 1909. Please give any pointers on how to install FontFoge Python module.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365299/how-to-import-fontforge-to-python-in-windows-7) help? And, also, have you actually installed Python on your system? It does not come pre-installed on Windows like other OSes.

Comment: I have installed Python (2.7.17 and 3.7.4, `python` and `py` respectively). I tried the answer but the `ffpython` only works with the batch file, which is very deep in folder structure. I tried added the PATH variable from the batch file, making `ffpython` accessible at all paths, but `ffpython` at other paths and `import fontforge` result in an error with dll files. Rebuilding is hard and I haven't tried that yet since I cant find the modules needed except Cygwin.