# Import multiple svg into FontForge in Windows

Tags: svg, fontforge

I have many svg files (around 24) and want to make the a font. I tried to use Fontforge but unfortunately  I have to import it one by one in the program. I find this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22124130/import-a-sequence-of-svg-files-into-fontforge-as-glyphs-and-output-a-font-file?rq=1) was used in Linux but I am a Windows user. Is there any method to import these files into Fontforge in bulk,specially in Windows? Sorry, I am newbie.

Comment: fontforge is supposed to work on windows but even if you manage the import you're in for a world of pain. Most fontforge users are on Linux (producting fonts that also work in Windows) and it shows

Answer (score 0):

FontForge has Python embedded. You can use the Linux method with that. Here's the output of `fontforge --help` reduced to the relevant details:

```
$ fontforge --help
fontforge [options] [fontfiles]
    -lang=py         use python for scripts (may precede -script)
    -lang=ff         use fontforge's legacy scripting language
    -script scriptfile   (executes scriptfile)
        must be the first option (or follow -lang).
        All others passed to scriptfile.
    -dry scriptfile      (syntax checks scriptfile)
        must be the first option. All others passed to scriptfile.
        Only for fontforge's own scripting language, not python.
    -c script-string     (executes argument as scripting cmds)
        must be the first option. All others passed to the script.

If a scriptfile is specified then FontForge will not open the X display
    nor will it process any additional arguments. It will execute the
    scriptfile and give it any remaining arguments
If the first argument is an executable filename, and that file's first
    line contains "fontforge" then it will be treated as a scriptfile.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a python script for this, Only tested on Linux but there is no reason that it wont work on Windows too. You can try it.

https://github.com/mnesarco/ff-batch